# PhoneGap Android iOS NFC

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cordova, cross-platform

I want to build an Cross-Platform App with PhoneGap. This App should run on Android and iPhone. The Android Version should be able to scan NFC Tags. Is it possible to do this with PhoneGap or do I have to write two native Apps, one for Android and one for iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Iphone has no NFC enabled devices yet. You can build the app with Phone GAP and will work in Android (there's a lot of blogs that explain how to do it) however not sure about if the app will launch in iphone due to it NFC required capabilities....
Today I suggest to write the app Native on Android... and wait a little to the Iphone 5.

Comment: Quick comment to this outdated answer: iPhone 5 has no NFC support. iPhone 6 does have it, though limited to Apple Pay payments. See http://www.nfcworld.com/nfc-phones-list/

Answer (score 1):

You can write a plugin for PhoneGap to provide the NFC capability of the platform you are on. Here's one for Android.
https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/

When iphone 5 comes out with NFC you can just write the plugin for iPhone and add it to your project.

**Update**: iPhone 5 doesn't have NFC. However iPhone 6 does, but only supports ApplePay and SDK/API is not yet provided by apple.